# Whenever user logs in, user should see "Hello (name of user)" from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve the name from the current user logged profile in my activity. Whenever user logs in, user should see "Hello (name of user)" from firebase. My login activity code is provided below. Now what I want is whenever I click on login button new activity comes i.e. my welcome page and it should display current logged user name

```
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignin);
    textViewSignup  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userLogin();
        }
    });
    textViewSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent a = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
        }
    });
}
private void userLogin(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    fb.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class));
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: Where do they set their Display Name? Or did you just want the UID?

Comment: Are you using facebook sign in?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply getting your user and then referencing to the name stored in your database

first get the user

```
myUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

and then just get the name

```
mDatabase.child("users").getChild(myUser).getchild("Username").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {

      String userName =  datasnapshot.getValue(String.class);

      //you can log your UserName to see that you actually have it
        Log.e("hello ",""+userName);

    }
}
```

where your mDatabase is this (in your onCreate)

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Also, if you dont have your database structured yet you can get the displayname of the user right from the mAuth like this

```
myUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
```

also for the email

```
myUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

remember that mAuth should be declared in your onCreate as below

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

PS: i just assume that your database is in that order, that you have your username inside the tree users / userID / Username

happy coding

Answer (score 1):

you should pass the name to the second activity using `putExtra` method on the intent

```
fb.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            String displayName = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , Welcome.class);
            intent.putExtra("DISPLAY_NAME" , displayName);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    }
});
```

in your `Welcome` activity get extract the value from the intent

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String displayName = intent.getStringExtra("DISPLAY_NAME");
    displayName = displayName == null ? "UNKOWN" : displayName;
    System.out.println(displayName);
    Toast.makeText(this , displayName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: getting error in  String displayName = FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();    //  errorget currentuser                                           String displayName = intent.getExtra().getString("DISPLAY_NAME" , "UNKNOWN");// error in .getextra

Comment: now i am stucked at (.getextra()) error is still there

Comment: actually its not returning name from the firebase well thanks

Comment: then the user doesn't have name , when account created the name is empty by default but you can change it

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid(); 
String name = user.getDisplayName();
```

You can use above lines of code to print logged in user name.